# Cannot save article changes via JCE depending on user permissions

Tags: caching, joomla, permissions, joomla-article, joomla-content-editor

We are using Joomla 1.5.21 and JCE 1.5.7 and have some trouble with the front end saving of articles.

Saving the article in the front end has no effect on the article stored in the database and therefore users on other devices cannot see the modification.

However, the changes ARE visible for the logged in user even after deleting the cache & cookies and reloading the page.

I noticed this behaviour only when the user is classified as an editor or publisher, if he is an author the editor doesn't store any of the changes!

How can I get the article changes to save?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a stackoverflow-type question. This seems more tech support... It may help, however, to see this site/some related code.

Comment: Questions of this type are always welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Salem for your comment but finally we could solve the problem by ourself. The problem was caused by joomfish or more by my OS. I am using a german OS which sometimes switches from english to german on its own, so that we had two different (language) versions in the back- and frontend.

Comment: This looks like less of an answer than it does an extension of the diagnostic findings.  What exactly did you do to overcome the issue?  (researchers will want to know)